# Is it faster to compute values before using them within an event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

This may be a dumb question, but let's say I'm creating event handlers for a class of elements, and each event handler depends on some specific computations for the particular element to which it's assigned. I'd assume the event handler will respond faster if the computations are done in advance and then placed in the handler, like this for example:

```
        $('.myElements').each(function () {

            // Computations

            $(this).click(function () {

               // Handler using computations

            });

        });
```

As opposed to this:

```
        $('.myElements').click(function () {

               // Computations
               // Handler using computations

        });
```

I'd assume the first approach will result in faster firing because the computation is done in advance of the actual click event. But is that necessarily the case?  I ask because I'm comparing the two, and at least anecdotally, the latter approach seems to be as fast as the first, if not faster. And the computations I'm concerned about are some unavoidable regexes.

Comment: Unless the computations are *extremely* CPU-intensive, it's not something to worry about, especially in reference to a click handler (users are much slower than computers :) ) First code block will take more resources upfront, but the click handler will perform (very slightly) faster, second code block will be the reverse.

Comment: Assume 1000 such elements the first has to do all those computations immediately on page load whereas the second only has to do them on demand for instance specific event occurrence and not until the event occurs. Page load is hectic with lots of script doing different things, IMO better to only do the computations when needed

Comment: A few times I have used [Console.time()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Console/time) for performance meassurements, you can do some testing with this method. In your case, the first approach will consume more time at document load. So, unless the computation takes too much time, in the way that you note ir affect the user experience, I will go with the second approach.

Comment: If you really want to get fancy could also do the computations in a webWorker thread which runs separate from code in main thread